# How to retrive value from objects by checking test condition in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have one array like

`filterVal = [AB, BC, DE];`
and millions of record. I need to check if `record.property` value is matching with any of the filterVal then `return true` else false.

Now problem in my code is When iterate 2nd index the first value is washed. Can any one tell me how to achive this.

My code.

```
for(var i=0; i<filterVal.length; i++){

        grid.store.filterBy(function(record){
            debugger;
          if(filterVal[i]==record.data[filterProperty])
             return true;
          else
             return false;
        });
    }

**Note** : When Going to i=2; all data washed away from 1st one.
```

Comment: Can't you just use `indexOf` to check if the value is contained in the array?

Comment: I would convert `filterVal` array into a hash or map in the first place. This will avoid you to make millions of wasteful `indexOf` searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're using Extjs, is that the case? If so you might want to tag your question.

Here's what I would do:

```
grid.store.filterBy(function(record){
  return filterVal.indexOf(record.data[filterProperty]) !== -1
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first convert the `filterBy` array into a hash like

```
{ AB: true, BC: true, DE: true }
```

for performance. The folowing should do the rest.

```
var filterMap = ["AB", "BC", "DE"].reduce((p,c) => Object.assign(p,{[c]:true}),{});
    result    = grid.store.filterBy(record => filterMap[record.data[filterProperty]]);
```

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you. Thanks for answer.